# Polynomial Regression with too many features

Tags: regression, machine-learning, scikit-learn, polynomial

I have a dataset with 10,000 datapoints for every of the 900 features and a target of 10,000 datapoints, so x = (10000, 900) and y = (10000, 1). If I plot the results for the first 100 features on the x-axis and the target on the y-axis I get the following relationship:

[image: data plot]

One can immediately spot a distinct relationship. When I try to apply a polynomial regressor of second degree I always run into memory errors. I guess it's because the amount of data is just too big. Is there any other model or strategy I can use to deal with the vast amount of features?

Comment: I don't see a distinct relationship. Anyway, you can try biglm or something similar in R (you are using R?), otherwise, with such big data, you can just take a sample of it, it should be good enough.

Comment: Have you tried dimensionality reduction, eg. PCA?

Comment: @IgorF. Yes, it reduced the amount of features by 3 of 900.

Comment: This really shouldn’t be a problem. MNIST has 784 features and 60,000 images, and MNIST runs easily on older machines. What kind of hardware do you have? For many reasonable, you may want to explore dimensionality reduction techniques, but 900 isn’t that many features. Do you mean that you reduced your feature count from 900 to 897?

Comment: @Dave I use a Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250 CPU at 1.60 GHz, 4 cores, and 16 GB of RAM. And yes, when I select to guess the dimensionalities, so n_components == 'mle' and svd_solver == 'full' of sklearn.decomposotion.PCA https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html